# If I draw three cards, what is the probability that one of them is higher than 10.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Exercise:** Suppose I have 100 cards marked 1 to 100. Let's say that I draw three cards. What is the probability that at least one of them is marked with number 10 or lower?

**My approach:** If I name the cards $A, B$, and $C$, then at least one of them is marked with number 10 or lower in the following cases:

- A is 10 or lower, B is higher than 10, C is higher than 10
- A is 10 or lower, B is 10 or lower, C is higher than 10
- A is 10 or lower, B is 10 or lower, C is 10 or lower
- A is higher than 10, B is 10 or lower, C is higher than 10
- A is higher than 10, B is 10 or lower, C is 10 or lower
- A is higher than 10, B is higher than 10, C is 10 or lower

I first thought I could just sum the probabilities of these events. That is

$$
P(\text{at least one of $A,B,C$ is marked with number 10 or lower})= (0.1 * 0.9 * 0.9) + (0.1 * 0.1 * 0.9) + ... + (0.9 * 0.9 * 0.1)
$$
Unfortunately, I don't think this is correct, because some of the events are overlapping. Furthermore, I don't think this is the smartest way to do this.

**Question:** How should I approach this exercise? What is the best way to look at these type of problems?

Comment: Do you replace the cards after each draw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P(\text{At least one of A, B, C} \le 10) = 1 - P(\text{All of A, B, C} \ge 10)$.

$P(\text{All of A, B, C} \ge 10) = 0.9 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.9 = 0.729$.

So your answer is $1-0.729 = \boxed{0.271}$

With these types of problems you might want to consider the probability of the opposite of the desired outcome and do $1$ minus that.

Comment: Note that this assumes the cards are chosen with replacement; without replacement, the actual probability of none of the cards are small is slightly lower, in the neighborhood of 0.727

Comment: also it must be $>10$.

Answer (score 2):

There are three disjoint cases, that cover the situation when at least one of the cards is $10$ or lower. Those are:

1) First card is $10$ or lower. Probability of that is $\frac{1}{10}$

2) First card is higher than $10$, but second card is $10$ or lower. The probability of that is $\frac{9}{10} \frac{10}{99} = \frac{1}{11}$

3) First and second cards are higher than $10$, but the third one is $10$ or lower. The probability of that is $\frac{9}{10} \frac{89}{99} \frac{10}{98} = \frac{89}{1078}$

Thus $\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{11} +  \frac{89}{1078} = \frac{67}{245}$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Note that my answer covers the case, when cards are chosen without replacement. For for the case, when the cards are chosen with replacement, see the answer by @ShreyJoshi.

Comment: It goes a little faster if you calculate the probability that all three cards are _greater_ than $10$: this is obviously $\frac{90}{100}\frac{89}{99}\frac{88}{98}=\frac{178}{245}$. By the way, your $2685$ in the final line should be $2695$, which cancels to give $\frac{67}{245}$. And $\frac{178}{245}$ is equal to $1-\frac{67}{245}$, as expected.